# Read lines from istringstream ,without '\r' char at the end

Tags: c++, getline, istringstream

I have a following function :

```
void process (std::string str)
{
    std::istringstream istream(str);
    std::string line;
    std::string specialStr("; -------- Special --------------------\r"); // win
    //std::string specialStr("; -------- Special --------------------"); //linux
    while (getline(istream,line))
    {
      if (strcmp(specialStr.c_str(), line.c_str()) != 0)
      {
          continue;
      }
      else
      {
         //special processing
      }
    }
}
```

I read the lines from std::istringstream line by line,using `getline` ,until i "meet" special string
after which i should do some special processing for the next lines.
The special string is:

`; -------- Special --------------------`
When I read the corresponding line  line in windows it ends with '\r' :

(`; -------- Special --------------------\r`)
In Linux no '\r' appears at the end.
Is there a way to read the lines consistently without distinguish if it is linux or windows?

Thanks

Comment: Have you perhaps opened the stream in binary mode?

Comment: std::string str; // is an argument std::istringstream isaStream(str);//this way I open the stringstream

Comment: And where do you get the content of `str` from? (you could post some code, you know)

Comment: I get str as an argument.I will post some code - you are right

Comment: @jrok - I have updated with the code as you requested

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can remove the '\r' from the end using this code:

```
if(line[line.length() - 1] == '\r') line = line.substr(0, line.length() - 1);
```

You can wrap this into a function if you want to:

```
std::istream& univGetline(std::istream& stream, std::string& line)
{
    std::getline(stream, line);
    if(line[line.length() - 1] == '\r') line = line.substr(0, line.length() - 1);
    return stream;
}
```

Integrated into your function:

```
void process (std::string str)
{
    std::istringstream istream(str);
    std::string line;
    std::string specialStr("; -------- Special --------------------");

    while (univGetline(istream,line))
    {
      if (strcmp(specialStr.c_str(), line.c_str()) != 0)
      {
          continue;
      }
      else
      {
         //special processing
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes - this is possible to do - Thanks.But I preferred to call some built-in function to get rid/ignore '\r' char